# ajax serialize() and $_POST receivend not working

Tags: php, serialization

type1 .. working

```
function aaa (frm_id){ var formData = new FormData($("#"+frm_id)\[0\]);var html_source = "";//console.log(formData); $.ajax({ cache : false, url : "a.php", type : 'POST',data : formData, async: false,contentType: false, processData: false,success : function(data) { .... } }
```

type2 .. not working this code...

```
function aaa (frm_id){ //var formData = new FormData($("#"+frm_id)\[0\]);var html_source = ""; var formData = $("#"+frm_id).serialize(); console.log(formData); $.ajax({ cache : false, url : "a.php", type : 'POST',data : formData, async: false,contentType: false, processData: false,success : function(data) { .... } }
```

i'm testing 2 type code a.php received page print_r($_POST) run type1  code is work normally but  type2 not working...

type2 before the submit console.log result is..
`prc_key=U3d2YUJZT0FyN3VOTHlOOS82UlYrZz09&prc_type=WlBoMnpVb2RaWUZZZUgzdGV4dzAyQT09&pagenum=1&bh_cate_section=&search_key=`

but a.php  print_r($_POST); is empty..

i don't know reason.... tell me please..

Comment: Why comment in type2? //var formData = new FormData

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/formatting. Please [edit] your question to make the code readable